# Outbound rate limiting (with a buffer) per IP

Tags: rate-limiting, outboundrules

My software has to interact via HTTP requests with several third party services, and these service enforce a rate limiter policy on their side. If I go above the rate limit, my server which is running my software might get banned by IP.

Is there a way to implement an *outbound* rate limiter **outside** of my software stack with common networking tools (like iptables and the likes)? Ideally, this rate limiter would have a buffer, so that if I exceed the outbound rate limit for a given IP, the connection will simply be delayed instead of dropped.

This would release me from the burden of adding this complexity to the code that is supposed to handle only my business logic. Also, I'm really curious about this! :)

Comment: I think you would get better answers on SO, but I am also curious if this could be done solely server-side.

Comment: IPTables the ability to rate limit connections, however the rate-limits are applied on the throughput of packets / second. Packets might not match well with API level requests.